# multiple uses of the same validator on a data property

Tags: angularjs, validation, breeze

We have a scenario in our application where we would like to use multiple instances of the same validator on the same breeze data property. However, when we enter multiple instances of the same validator on the same breeze property, only the last one affects the validation state of that property. This is because the key for breeze errors is propertyName + validatorName.

Example:

```
    "dataProperties": [
    {
            "name": "fieldA",
            "dataType": "String",
            "validators": [
                {
                      "name": "requiredCond",
                      "context": {
                          "messageTemplate": " fieldA is required if fieldB has    a value.",
                          "dependencyName": "fieldB"
                     }
                  },
              {
                      "name": "requiredCond",
                      "context": {
                          "messageTemplate": " fieldA is required if fieldC has a value.",
                          "dependencyName": "fieldC"
                     }
                  }
            ] 
        }
   ]
```

Is there any configuration or custom overriding to enable this behavior?

> “one potential solution would be to create multiples of these
>   validators in breeze, like ‘requiredCond1’, ‘requiredCond2’,
>   ‘requiredCond3’ etc. that all actually point to the same validator
>   code, that way the error key would be unique….but we would like to
>   avoid this as it seems pretty ‘hacky’ “

Thanks.